# Perl: Looping over input lines with an index-based approach

Tags: perl, text-processing

This is a beginner-best-practice question in perl. I'm new to this language. The question is:

If I want to process the output lines from a program, how can I format THE FIRST LINE in a special way?

I think of two possibilities:

1) A flag variable, once the loop is executed first time is set. But it will be evaluated for each cycle. BAD solution

2) An index-based loop (like a "for"). Then I would start the loop in i=1. This solution is far better. The problem is HOW CAN I DO IT?

I just found the code for looping over with the while ( <> ) construct.

Here you can see better:

```
$command_string = "par-format 70j p0 s0 < " . $ARGV[0] . "|\n";                                                                                

open DATA, $command_string  or die "Couldn't execute program: $!";

print "\t    <div>&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;|-- <strong>Description</strong></div>\n";
while ( defined( my $line = <DATA> )  ) {
   chomp($line);
   # print "$line\n";
   print "\t    <div>&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;|&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;&‎nbsp;-- " . $line  . "</div>\n";
}

close DATA;
```

Please also don't hesitate in correcting any code in here, this is my first perl poem.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, replacing the &nbsp; with &amp;&nbsp; doesn't work.  I smell a bug is SO.

Comment: Can anyone give me a similar solution to TIE that I can use with the fifo!

Comment: warning: there is now U+200e characters in there to trick SO 's formatter into not sucking. Copy-pasting the above code will be unlikely to work as expected, and will likely print *literal* &nbsp; on your page :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always use `$.` or the English name `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` to control the logic in your loop with:

```
while (my $line = <>) {
    if ($. == 1) {
        # do cool stuff here
    }
    # do normal stuff here
}
```

Comment: yep, that's the first approach. I prefer the second, but this is a fix for the problem. THanks!

Comment: I guess if this is so voted is because is better approach, isn't it?

Comment: hum... but although the TIE solution doesn't work, it has the very good quality of leting me access arbitrary lines. How could I do that in this way? The conditions can become too complicated if a have changes in several lines.

Answer (score 5):

To handle the first line differently, you could just put

```
$line = <DATA>;
```

above your loop.

With proper checking for read problems (empty file, etc.) this should be

```
if ($line = <DATA>) {
    ...do special things...
}

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    ...do regular things...
}
```

I'm not sure about the `defined()` call. You might not need it, since an empty string has a false truth value.

Comment: The defined() call is unnecessary - see "man perlop" - Perl adds it implicitly when you do while(<fh>)

Comment: You need the defined call in the if, but not in the while, whiles have a bit of magic that tests for definedness instead of truth when the function is readline (aka <>), glob (also aka <>), or readdir.

Answer (score 4):

From a 'best practices' perspective there is much wrong with that code sample:

```
open DATA, $command_string  or die "Couldn't execute program: $!";
```

- Security hole, please exploit me.
- DATA is a magical value that points to a `__DATA__` section at the end of the current file.
- You should use

  ```
  open my $fh
  ```

  Which uses a lexical variable for a file handle instead of a global.
- You should use 3 arg open, ie:

  ```
  open my $fh, '<'  , $filename
  open my $fh, '-|' , $command
  open my $fh, '-|' , $command, @args
  ```

  sadly I have yet to work out how 3-arg works with dual-pipes. 
  theres' this IPC::Open2 thing, but I haven't worked out how 
  to use that effectively yet. Suggestions welcome .

Comment: This proves that copy-pasting code from internet is a dangerous practice. Thanks for your answer.